# Modify JSON keys with ObjectMapper in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I'm receiving the following json from the API:

```
[ { "first_id": 1,
    "second_objs": [ { "second_id": 2,
                       "third_objs": [ { "third_id": 3,
                                         "param": "abcd" }] } ] } ]
```

And serialising it using ObjectMapper:

```
class First: NSObject, Mappable {
    var first_id: Int?
    var second_objs: [Second]?

    required init?(_ map: Map){}
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        first_id <- map["first_id"]
        second_objs <- map["second_objs"]
    }
}

class Second: NSObject, Mappable {
    var second_id: Int?
    var third_objs: [Third]?

    required init?(_ map: Map){}
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        second_id <- map["second_id"]
        third_objs <- map["third_objs"]
    }
}

class Third: NSObject, Mappable {
    var third_id: Int?
    var param: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){}
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        third_id <- map["third_id"]
        param <- map["param"]
    }
}
```

Now after recieving and modifying that JSON I need to send it back to the API.
However before sending back I need to rename keys "second_objs" and "third_objs" to "something_else_2" and "something_else_3".

```
[ { "first_id": 1,
    "something_else_2": [ { "second_id": 2,
                            "something_else_3": [ { "third_id": 3,
                                                    "param": "abcd" }] } ] } ]
```

How do I do the renaming in a clean way?